# Sorting-Algorithm for multiple column sort behind jQuery tablesorter plugin

Tags: sorting, tablesorter

I figured out that when i'm using the multiple column sort function of the plugin.
The first row gets sorted properly and the second row items where the first row items are the same are getting sorted.

I have two columns with percentages in it and would like to sort them from the highest added score (from the sum of both columns) to the lowest.

```
So: 0.9 | 0.2    Rather then: 0.9 | 0.2
    0.6 | 0.4                 0.7 | 0.1
    0.6 | 0.3                 0.6 | 0.4
    0.7 | 0.1                 0.6 | 0.3
    0.3 | 0.4                 0.3 | 0.4
```

Is this behaviour possible within jquery-tablesorter?

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to do this... you might end up needing to write a custom sorting script. But I won't give in, I'll see what I can come up with for you :)

Comment: I would be fine with writing a custom sorting script, but I don't know where to hook in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I'm switching to the jQuery DataTables Plugin. It allows to define own sorting functions and other fancy stuff.